# How to multiply all elements in a row with corresponding element in same row in different column in pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multiplication

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:
[image]

I want to multiply elements in a row except for the "depreciation_rate" column with the value in the same row in the "depreciation_rate" column.

I tried `df2.iloc[:,6:26]*df2["depreciation_rate"]` as well as `df2.iloc[:,6:26].mul(df2["depreciation_rate"])`

I get the same results with both which look as follows. I get NaN values with additional columns which I don't want. I think the elements in rows also multiply with values in other rows in the "depreciation_rate" column. What would be a good way to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**`mul()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) along `axis=0`:

```py
df2.iloc[:,6:26].mul(df2["depreciation_rate"], axis=0)
```